# jquery slider toggles from both direction

Tags: jquery

i have this jquery function what happens is that profilecontain slides from bottom to up then top to bottom . but, when it slides it opens from both direction top and bottom whereas i want it be a smooth slide from bottom to top and top to bottom.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#profilelink").toggle( function(){
                    $("#profilelink").animate({"top": "237px"}, "slow");
                    $("#profilees").animate({"height": "290px", "top": "-165px"}, "slow");
                    //$("#newses").animate({"height": "310px"}, "slow");
                    $("#profilecontain").animate({"height": "270px", 'top': '-154px'}, "slow");
            }, function(){
                    $("#profilelink").animate({"top": "527px"}, 'slow');
                    $("#profilees").animate({"height": "0px", "top": "8px"}, 'slow');
                    $("#profilecontain").animate({"height": "0px", "top": "0px"}, 'slow');
            });
        });
```

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: i don't know much about jquery learned it recently . you can view the effest on www.webtofun.com/index.php

Comment: done with my problem if anybody faces similar problem it was just due to wrong calculation of pixels